# Symmetry and Skew-Symmetry in covariant derivatives

Tags: tensors

Okay,so,

E$_i$$_j$ is a rank 2 symmetric tensor. So,

E$_i$$_j$= E$_j$$_i$

So, when there is,

E$_i$$_j$,$_k$$_l$$_t$ where the comma indicates covariant differentiation with respect to the indices k, l and t, how do I go about finding the relationship between 
E$_i$$_j$,$_k$$_l$$_t$ and say 
E$_i$$_j$,$_l$$_t$$_k$

That is, how do I know when I swap the indices or permute them in some order, what relation they will have with say another combination of permuted indices?
That is,how should I go about finding the relationship between
 E$_i$$_j$,$_k$$_l$$_t$ and say 
E$_i$$_j$,$_l$$_t$$_k$ . Will they be related with a minus sign as in the case of skew-symmetry or no?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the context within which you are taking these covariant derivatives... generally speaking though, covariant derivatives along two vector fields $v, w$ will commute if the Lie bracket $[v,w]$ vanishes.

Comment: C$_i$$_j$$_k$$_l$,$_t$+C$_j$$_k$$_l$$_t$,$_i$ + C$_k$$_l$$_t$$_i$,$_j$ + C$_l$$_t$$_i$$_j$,$_k$+C$_t$$_i$$_j$$_k$,$_l$= zero

 and C$_i$$_j$$_k$$_l$= D$_i$$_j$$_k$,$_l$ + D$_j$$_k$$_l$,$_i$ + D$_k$$_l$$_i$,$_j$ + D$_l$$_i$$_j$,$_k$ and



C$_i$$_j$$_k$$_l$ is the curl of D$_i$$_j$$_k$
also,
D$_i$$_j$$_k$= -D$_j$$_i$$_k$=-D$_i$$_k$$_j$=-D$_k$$_j$$_i$

Comment: @user7530: The above identity is what I wanted to prove. D$_i$$_j$$_k$ is the curl of E$_i$$_j$$_k$

Comment: The problem is, if I expand everything, I get a big mess with nothing cancelling out. So, I thought if I kept it compact( the notation with the commas), I thought that would help cancel out the terms under some symmetry or skew-symmetry. Please help.